# Calculate the height reached when 1/3 of original Kinetic Energy is lost

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy, kinematics

I am sorry for asking this low level question but there is a confusion, I am not overcoming from hours.

My book asks me to solve the following problem:

> When an object is thrown upward, it rises to a height $h$. How high is the object in terms of $h$ when it has lost $\frac{1}{3}$ of its original kinetic energy?

My book give me the answer $\frac{1}{3}h$

and I think it should be $\frac{2h}{3}$ because if we divide the $h$ by $3$ then every single segment would be covered by object due to $\frac{1}{3}$ of Kinetic energy. Now if I throw the body upward such that the its kinetic energy is $\frac{2}{3}$ of the previous kinetic energy than it will reach a height $\frac{2h}{3}$.

How to solve it in correct way?

Comment: I think you are interpreting the question as "If the object is thrown upward with 1/3 less kinetic energy, what maximum height will it reach?", while the book means "If the object is thrown upward with the same original kinetic energy, at what height will the object have lost 1/3 of its kinetic energy?".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your thought about dividing the length in segments is fine. But be careful to interpret this correctly.

Think about how high the object is if it has 0/3 and 3/3 of the original kinetic energy. That should help you understand why 1/3 is the correct answer.